# Design won't show in blender

Tags: animation, mesh, objects

I created some things on Marvelous Designer and did the step by step to export the documents for blender, now when I import the obj content it will not show. The name and everything appears but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I've tried watching YouTube tutorials but none of them seem to be helping and were from 6+ years ago, I'm using a Mac if that's any help

[image]

[image]

Comment: maybe it's very small and you need to scale up?

Comment: Try deleting the default cube and scrolling right in. If that doesn't help try @moonboots suggestion and if that doesn't work we'll need to see your Blend file. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page and then edit your question here and paste the link into it assuming it isn't over 30Meg in size.

Comment: @JohnEason I hope that works? I didn't have a clue how to work it haha.

Comment: Yes that's fine. I'll post an answer shortly.

Comment: As far as I remember, the scaling factor for MD without correction is 1000 ...so the object is either much too small or much too large.

Comment: Much too large in this case! :^)

Answer (score 0):

Your object has been imported with the origin a long way away from the mesh and at a very large scale. Select the object in the outliner then hit the <kbd>N</kbd> key to show the size of the object!

[image]

You can scale it down using <kbd>S 0.01</kbd> to reduce it's size which will bring it into view

[image]

Now use the <kbd>Object</kbd> > <kbd>Set Origin</kbd> > <kbd>Geometry to Origin</kbd> menu to move the object to its origin and rotate it to the correct orientation using <kbd>R X 90</kbd>.

[image]

Finally apply the rotation using <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd> > <kbd>Rotation</kbd> and you may want to reduce the scale further before applying it with <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd> > <kbd>Scale</kbd>.

Incidentally, you can import with a different scale and rotation by hitting the <kbd>N</kbd> key while you're in the file selector. But I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader! :^)

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm so dumb, but I appreciate you showing step by step <3 you saved me the hassle of searching so much videos!

Comment: No problem You can accept my answer as correct if you wish.